# Way to choose 'null' values in a badge list in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I currently have badge list as a filter for a table.
When you click on the value, this url is run:

`'f?p='||:APP_ID||':5:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P5_VALUE::' url`

And this is how I'm calling the table:

```
select ROWID...
  from Table
  WHERE (:P5_Value is null OR Value = :P5_Value)
```

I have the "P5_Value is null" b/c I want to have the option when a user clicks the reset button to be able to see all the values again (reset the filters). 

So the problem I'm having is that when I click on the 'unassigned' filter, the tables don't get filtered properly since the 'unassigned' value are all null right now. So I'm guessing that it's getting confused with the 'reset' function? So I was wondering if anyone knew how to solve this issue?

For reference, this is how I'm creating the filter, once the badge is clicked:
`'f?p='||:APP_ID||':5:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P5_VALUE::' url`

Comment: Does the P5_UNASSIGNED item have a default value?  Does the LOV have "Show Null" = Yes?

Comment: yes, LOV have "show null" = yes. and P5_Unassigned? do you mean P5_Value? no it doesn't

Comment: OK, sorry I don't really know what you mean by the "unassigned" filter.  I assumed you meant a filter on a column that represents an "unassigned" status or something like that.  Maybe you just meant a filter that hasn't got a value selected?  Maybe some screenshots would make your question clearer?

Comment: I added a screenshot. So 'Priorities' filter has the values 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', and 'Unassigned'. When you select any of the filters, it selects all the rows where priorities = 'A' for 'A', 'B' for 'B', 'C' for 'C', 'D' for 'D' and null for 'unassigned' (b/c some of the rows has priorities = null). I'm having an issue with 'null' b/c the way I'm showing all the values right now (the screenshot you see above, basically having no filters) is through the where statement ":P5_Value is null". So when you click on any of the unassigned filter, it doesn't filter correctly b/c of the where statement

Comment: So the only options I can think of is to get rid of the where statement. But the issue I have with that is that when you load the page, no values show up until you select a value. But I need it to show all the values in the beginning. lmk if you have any questions. sorry if this isn't that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments below your question, I **think** maybe you need this?

```
select ROWID...
  from Table
  WHERE (:P5_Value is null 
        OR :P5_Value = 'U' and Value is null
        OR Value = :P5_Value
        )
```

Then modify the LOV for P5_Value so that it includes value 'U' for 'Unassigned'.